# Compare two integer products without overflow

Tags: c++

I need to find whether `a*b >= c*d` where `a,b,c,d` are signed 32-bit integers ('int' on my machine).

Is it possible to compare those products using only 32-bit signed integers without overflow so that result is correct for all possible values?

I thought about `a/d >= c/b`.

However it fails on '2*7 >= 3*5' (false) because '2/5 >= 3/7' ('0 >= 0') is true.

Comment: '2/5 >= 3/7' is not true, check again

Comment: Ok, it is true if you are using int arithmetic (it will be like comparing 0 >= 0).

Comment: Read carefully - 32 bit signed integers - that is 'int' in C++.

Comment: @Somnium Not necessarily.

Comment: @Somnium: Usually--but `int` is only really guaranteed to be at least 16 bits, not necessarily 32 bits.

Comment: Then switch to non-integer arithmetic: (double)a/d >= (double)c/b.

Comment: @bialpio Did you notice the -3 answer below? OP wants only int arithmetic

Comment: @JerryCoffin OK, I need to use only integral types that are same that 'a,b,c,d' use.

Comment: Any reason you can't perform 64-bit x 64-bit arithmetic?

Comment: I would say that what you want is impossible. If you don't have 64-bit arithmetic available, you must implement it yourself. If ever there was a case for using an in-line assembler, this is it.

Comment: @TonyK: Please clarify how assembly language would provide a benefit in this context.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: in most assembly languages (that have a multiplication instruction available) the multiplication will produce a result twice the operand size, making the comparison (and lack of overflow) trivial.

Comment: For performance, the division check sucks.  I suggest copying the values into 64-bit quantities and multiplying.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: What I'm alluding to is that if the variables are placed into 64-bit integers before the multiplication, there will be no no need for assembly language.

Comment: What if I had 'a,b,c,d' 64-bit? There is no 128-bit integers on most machines.

Comment: InlineAsm: Doesn´t this violate the 32bit requirement too?

Comment: @Thomas: For instance, the Intel `IMUL` instruction can compute the 64-bit product of two 32-bit signed integers. This is much faster than promoting two 32-bit integers to 64 bits and performing 64 x 64-bit multiplication.

Comment: @deviantfan That's only example why I may need only using same size integers for calculating.

Comment: @Somnium I understand, I didn´t mean your comment in the first place.

Comment: Emulate 64 bit arithmetic using the 32 bit integers. That is also what we did before we had 64 bit machines...

Comment: @KlamerSchutte How it can be done efficiently?

Comment: KlamerSchutte is probably right (that there is no other way). Use two 32bit ints together for one number and write functions like multiplication etc. yourself for this data structure. Very slow, but... (I had some wacky idea with prime factorization, but it has a problem with some numbers)

Comment: @Somnium how approximate are we allowed to be?

Comment: @IdeaHat I need exact result, that's why no floating-point.

Comment: @Somnium More accurately, you need exact results, that's why you can drop any bits.

Comment: Does your C++ compiler not provide a signed 64 bit integer type?? Even on a 32-bit machine, the C++ compiler should happily multiply 64 bit numbers for you, no problem. (The compiler may need to emulate 64 bit arithmetic as @Klamer suggests of course, but it will do this silently and correctly under the hood.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the moment, I'm going to assume the inputs are signed integers.

This being the case, we want to start by checking the signs. If one side is negative and the other positive, that's enough to tell us the result (negative is obviously smaller than positive) so we're done.

If both sides of the equality will be positive or both negative, we cache the sign for the result, then get rid of the signs so we can deal with unsigned numbers for the multiplication itself.

Once we have unsigned numbers, we can do the multiplication by treating each 32-bit integer as the sum of two different numbers, one representing the lower bits and one the upper bits of the input number. So, you'd convert each of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` to two numbers with only 16 significant bits. So, for the left side, we'd have:

```
al = a & 0xffff;
au = a >> 16;

bl = b & 0xffff;
bu = b >> 16;
```

So:

```
a * b
```

...is the same as:

```
(al + au << 16) * (bl + bu << 16)
```

and using the distributive property, we can turn that into:

```
al * bl + au<<16 * bl + al * bu<<16 + au<<16 * bu<<16
```

Since `a * (b * c)` = `(a * b) * c`, we can do all the bit-shifts *after* we do the other multiplications, so this turns into:

```
al * bl +            // we'll call this intermediate result "lower"
(au * bl) << 16 +
(al * bu) << 16 +    // we'll call the sum of these two "mid" 
(au * bu) << 32      // we'll call this one "upper"
```

Now the important point: our bit-masking ensures that each multiplication step has inputs that only have 16 significant bits apiece, so each intermediate result will only have 32 significant bits, so each will fit into a single 32-bit integer without overflowing.

From there, we have to sum the terms. This is slightly non-trivial, but still fairly tractable. First, we have to figure out whether the sum of a term will create a carry. One way to do this is like this:

```
bool carry(unsigned a, unsigned b) { 
    return a > (std::number_limits<unsigned>::max() - b);
}
```

Then our result is lower + mid<<16 + upper << 32. Since we're dealing in 32-bit integers, it's probably easiest to take `mid` and split it into an upper and a lower half. Its lower half will be added to `lower`, and its upper half to `upper`. Our result will then be spread across two (unsigned) 32-bit integers, one containing `lower + mid_lower`, the other containing `upper + mid_upper + carries`.

From there it's a simple matter of recovering the signs we stored at the beginning, then comparing the upper halves and if and only if they're equal, comparing the lower halves.

If your numbers start out unsigned, then you can just kind of skip lightly over the parts that involve signs.

Comment: Most likely we can optimize as we are interested in `a*b > c*d`, i.e. `(a*b)-(c*d) > 0`. For example, if `ah*bh-ch*dh` is bigger than 0x20001 you can be sure that `a*b > c*d`. 0x20001 is my (estimate) for the maximum the sums of the lower significant 16 bit multiplies+carry.

Comment: @KlamerSchutte: Yes, you can optimize by looking first at the upper word, and if it's enough different, that gives your answer without further computation.

Comment: Probably not optimal or even right, but I wrote some code. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54ff50837882c950

Comment: @MooingDuck: That code confirms my comment that in-line assembly language is the way to go!

Comment: @TonyK: Oh definitely.  C++ can't access the high parts of a multiply or add, which means you have to break it into many steps.  ASM can simply do a multiply, then compare the tops, then compare the bottoms.  It should be 8 ASM instructions or so. (mul, get hi, get lo, mul, get hi, get lo, branchge, branchge)  (Note my code is slightly longer than necessary because I try to do a quick bailout if the top 15/31 bits differ before calculating the full results)

Comment: `a > (std::number_limits<unsigned>::max() - b)` can be changed to much simpler `a > ~b` (works only for unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Use a bigint library.  [Boost has one.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
bool BigintCompareProducts(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
  using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
  return cpp_int(a) * cpp_int(b) >= cpp_int(c) * cpp_int(d);
}
```

**Option 2**

Building off of your `a/d >= c/b` idea, you can add logic to check the remainders. I haven't extensively tested this, and it doesn't currently negative numbers.

```
// Returns 1, 0, or -1 if a is >, ==, or < b
template<typename T>
int cmp(T a, T b)
{
  return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
}

// Returns 1, 0, or -1 if n1/d1 is >, ==, or < n2/d2
int CompareFractions(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2)
{
  int f1 = n1 / d1;
  int f2 = n2 / d2;
  int result = cmp(f1, f2);
  if (result != 0) {
    return result;
  }

  // Equal fractions - remainder may make them different
  int r1 = n1 % d1;
  int r2 = n2 % d2;
  if (r1 == 0 || r2 == 0) {
    // Any zero remainder is less than any positive fraction.
    return cmp(r1, r2);
  } else {
    return -1 * CompareFractions(d1, n1 % d1, d2, n2 % d2);
  }
}

// Returns 1, 0, or -1 if a * b >, ==, or < c * d
int CompareProducts(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
  return CompareFractions(a, d, c, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this fit *perfectly* your needs but you should try this:

```
int a, b, c, d;
// set them for a*b=c*d

int one = a/d, two = c/b
int greatest = one;
if (two > greatest) greatest = two;
int k = pow(10.0, 8-log(greatest)); // log (INT_MAX) = 9

one = k*a/d;
two = k*c/b;

// if one > two then a*b > c*d
```

For 2×7 >= 3×5, you got 40000000 >= 42857142 so it's false as intended.